# Set tracking mode to cookie to remove appended session id, without using web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

I am setting up a completely java based spring app with no xml config :

```
public class WebApp extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebMvcConfigurer.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { mypackages })
public class WebMvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/static-assets/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

where do I put this, which used to be in my web.xml ?

```
 <session-config>
        <!-- Disables URL-based sessions (no more 'jsessionid' in the URL using Tomcat) -->
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do it as in below

```
public class WebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        HashSet<SessionTrackingMode> set = new HashSet<SessionTrackingMode>();
        set.add(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE);
        servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(set);

    }

}
```

Comment: Use `EnumSet.of`, this is **much** more efficient and a good habit to get into with collections on `Enum`.

Comment: `servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.COOKIE));` for the copy and paste crowd :P

Answer (score 9):

In a Spring Boot app, you can configure the mode using the [application property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) `server.session.tracking-modes`.

In your `application.properties` add:

```
server.session.tracking-modes=cookie
```

Or if you use `application.yml`:

```
server:
  session:
    tracking-modes: 'cookie'
```

The Spring Boot autoconfiguration internally uses the same call to `servletContext.setSessionTrackingModes` which Bassem recommended in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262937/1095318).

**UPDATE**

In newer versions of Springboot, use

```
server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie
```

Answer (score 2):

[Since 3.2.0.RC1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2156) this is available in the `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` like so:

```
public class WebSecutityInit extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Set<SessionTrackingMode> getSessionTrackingModes() {
        return EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.SSL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of [spring boot 2.4.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/htmlsingle/#server.servlet.session.tracking-modes) and later, the application property is renamed to server.**servlet**.session.tracking-modes.

So, in application.properties, need to add

```
server.servlet.session.tracking-modes="cookie"
```

If using application.yml, need to have

```
server:
    servlet:
        session:
            tracking-modes: cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, that works for me, has been the code below inside the SecurityConfig class.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
 http.httpBasic()
  .and()
  .sessionManagement()
  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //No sessionId eppended  
  ...
}
```